# unorderable types: str() < int() cannot change int to string to int - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I am trying to change a integer to string then back to integer due to it repeats till 100. For example, I have a multiple number and thefive number, it need's to do the sum then output it like print(multnum+"x5="+answer) in order to do that I must convert it to a string. This process repeats using while function so in order to do another sum using the multnum it must go back to a integer.

```
def output100_5table():
    answer = 0
    thefive = 5
    multnum = 0
    addmult = multnum+1
    thetimes = "x5="
    while answer < 100:
        addmult = int(multnum+1)
        answer = addmult*thefive
        addmult = str(addmult)
        answer = str(answer)
        print(addmult+thetimes+answer)
output100_5table()
```

Comment: So `answer` is a string, and you cannot compare it to an int (100 in your case). What's your question ? Just convert it to an int.

Comment: Or stop converting it to a str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? It was difficult to figure out what the code's purpose was.

```
>>> def show_table(multiplicand, product_limit):
    multiplier = 1
    while True:
        product = multiplicand * multiplier
        if product > product_limit:
            break
        print(multiplicand, 'x', multiplier, '=', product)
        multiplier += 1


>>> show_table(5, 100)
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
5 x 10 = 50
5 x 11 = 55
5 x 12 = 60
5 x 13 = 65
5 x 14 = 70
5 x 15 = 75
5 x 16 = 80
5 x 17 = 85
5 x 18 = 90
5 x 19 = 95
5 x 20 = 100
>>> def show_table(multiplicand, product_limit):
    for multiplier in range(1, product_limit // multiplicand + 1):
        print(multiplicand, 'x', multiplier, '=', multiplicand * multiplier)


>>> show_table(5, 100)
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
5 x 10 = 50
5 x 11 = 55
5 x 12 = 60
5 x 13 = 65
5 x 14 = 70
5 x 15 = 75
5 x 16 = 80
5 x 17 = 85
5 x 18 = 90
5 x 19 = 95
5 x 20 = 100
>>>
```